# Почему видео бесконечно обрабатывается в вк?

Tags: vkontakte-api

агружаю через

> video.save(link=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXlZfc1TrD0)

без name и description,чтобы взялось из ютуба. Потом кидаю в сообщения через

> messages.send(peer_id=2000000002,attachment=video16408003_456239093)

а там оно отображается как не обработанное.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы внимательно читали, что написано в документации ВК по поводу link?

Comment: Не понял немного. url для встраивания видео с внешнего сайта, например, с Youtube. В этом случае нужно вызвать полученный upload_url, не прикрепляя файл, достаточно просто обратиться по этому адресу.

Comment: «нужно вызвать полученный upload_url» — вот, а вы вызываете?

Comment: @andreymal куда вызывать? в параметр link в video.save ?

Comment: В http-запрос вызывать, «просто обратиться по этому адресу». Или вы не умеете обращаться по адресу?

Comment: @andreymal я выполняю самостоятельно пока что

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87093/discussion-between-kazio-and-andreymal).